# Bootstrap 4 Modal Is Not Closing When Loaded the Content via .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap 4 modal, which I load the body content externally via `.load()`. But it's not closing when I click on the close buttons. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

My JavaScript Code:

```
if(status){
   $('#cartMessage').load("modal.html")
   $('#cartMessage').modal("show");
  }
```

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cartMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cartMessageLabel">

 </div>
```

External Modal Body:

```html
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this might help you.

[Discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073241/bootstrap-4-modal-will-not-close-after-using-jquery-load). This has the same issue as yours I guess. You can trigger it manually.